# Unable to execute C Program executable using SSH Library (from Robot Framework)

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to use Robot Framework to SSH into a remote machine and execute a C program/executable.

But it appears that ROBOT is not executing this program. However, the SHH connection seems to be successful and it is able to find the script to execute.

```
echo "Starting Server Process" // This statement is printed.
./helloworld            // infinite loop program. Doesn't run (checked ps output

echo "Completed server program"  // also printed.
```

Is there any known issue where ROBOT is unable to execute C/C++ programs using the SSH library ?

I would be grateful if someone could share any insight on this

-Tej

---

Editing the main message

Starting up Exchange process on server.

```
${retval}=   Start Command    ./server.sh
BuiltIn.Sleep    30s
${output}=    Read Command Output
BuiltIn.Log To Console    Output from server ${output}
Should Contain    ${output}    Exchange server started
```

The issue here is that,

1) SSH works fine, because the echo statements are printed from the script
2) The 30 sec sleep is for me to check "ps -aef" output on the server machine to see if the process is started. (it is not)

~
~

Comment: Please show the robot commands you are running. There is no known problem, since most linux programs are C/C++ programs.

Comment: HI Bryan
Thanks for your quick reply 

Starting up Server process on server.
        ${retval}=   Start Command  ./server.sh
 
        BuiltIn.Sleep    30s 

        ${output}=    Read Command Output 

        BuiltIn.Log To Console    Output from server ${output}

        Log    ${output}

The perplexing thing is that everything else seems to be fine.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comment section, it's impossible to read. [edit] your question to add additional information.

Comment: Hi Bryan,
Thanks, I have edited the message as requested.
Kindly let me know if you require any further info